# SQL Server : transaction log used space

Tags: sql-server, logging

It's a little weird for me. I have a database (AdventureWorks2014; SQL Server 2014) in full recovery model.

Executing this script 3 times:

```
declare @i int = 0
declare @date datetime

while @i <= 1000
begin
    set @date = getdate()

    begin tran
        update Production.TransactionHistory 
        set TransactionDate = getdate(),
            ActualCost = @i + TransactionID
        where TransactionID % 3 = 0

    commit tran

    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

returns these results for the log file space usage:

```
select * from sys.dm_db_log_space_usage
```

```
12  4280279040  2110091264  49,29799    2101624832
12  4280279040  2120466432  49,54038    2101067776
12  4280279040  1261416448  29,47042    1238355968
```

I suspect each execution of script should increase log file usage / log file size in full recovery model... Why the first time I have  49% usage and the the third only 29% heaving the same total file size?

Of course there is no log backup...

Comment: Did the log file auto-grow during this process?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was lack of full backup after changing recovery model from simple to full